# How AlertManager and Prometheus statefulsets are created in prometheus-operator helm chart?

Tags: prometheus, kubernetes-helm, prometheus-alertmanager, prometheus-operator

## Request

Please explain how 2 StatefulSets are createad automatically when deploying prometheus-operator Helm chart. It'd be awesome if you could point me to the piece of the chart that pulls those 2 statefulsets.

## Reproduce

```
$ helm repo add stable https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com

$ helm install prom-op stable/prometheus-operator

$ kubectl get pods
NAME                                                   READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
alertmanager-prom-op-prometheus-operator-alertmanager-0   2/2     Running   0          49m
prom-op-grafana-78c44f8bc8-nvf45                          2/2     Running   0          49m
prom-op-kube-state-metrics-db84fc9d-smsk6                 1/1     Running   0          49m
prom-op-prometheus-node-exporter-87t5g                    1/1     Running   0          49m
prom-op-prometheus-operator-operator-8554b8f87-6hv9d      2/2     Running   0          49m
prometheus-prom-op-prometheus-operator-prometheus-0       3/3     Running   1          49m

$ kubectl get sts
NAME                                                 READY   AGE
alertmanager-prom-op-prometheus-operator-alertmanager   1/1     51m
prometheus-prom-op-prometheus-operator-prometheus       1/1     51m
```

As you can see 2 statefulsets are created, but I can't seem to understand how they get created.

## Context

There is a custom tailored prometheus-operator on my hands that does not pull 2 statefulsets for some reason. So far my analysis did not yield any clear understanding. All I end up with is grafana, kube-state-metrics, node-exporter and operator, and no statefulsets.

## Reference

[prometheus-operator Helm chart source](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/prometheus-operator)

Comment: It's look like the prometheus-operator code create the sts objects.

Comment: @Shmuel can you point me to the the piece of the code that in your opinion is responsoble for the creation of the statefulsets? I'd appreciate that very much.

Answer (score 3):

figured out that the CRD was responsible for creating those 2 statefulsets; turned out that the tailored prometheus-operator lacked service accounts for alertmanager, prometheus and prometheus-operator and RBAC to work properly.
I just copied those from the stable chart.